# How to suppress the exponential format when using decimal module in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

I am writing python code that requires precision up to 108 digits beyond the decimal point. For this, I am using the "decimal" module. In some calculations (example below), I get the result in the exponential format.
Example:

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec=100
result1 = Decimal(387) / Decimal(1577917828000)
#results are returned in JSON
```

The resulting value is `2.452599198340510796231399192987633827532874544592571774909941634806093337326815474702907026157258171E-10`
However, I need this in the normal (float?) format without the E-10.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `format(result1, 'f')` is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec=100
result1 = Decimal(387) / Decimal(1577917828000)
print('{:f}'.format(result1))
```

You need to use this,

```
'{:f}'.format(result1)
```

Comment: I'd suggest getting rid of the minimum field width `30` here: there's no good reason to pad to width 30 for results that fit in fewer digits. (Perhaps you meant `.30f` instead of `30f`, but even then, just using `f` is simpler and doesn't risk accidentally suppressing digits.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am going to edit it. Thanks for your kind feedback.